# Memory full error when exporting crystal report to pdf

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, vb6

we have a legacy application written in visual basic 6.0. This application first saves the rendered crystal report into a directory as a pdf document. Then we take that document and store in database as a blob. Following is a snippet of the code. When the application has to render reports for say 1000 employees, it runs half-way through and throws "Memory full" error on ".Export false" line. If I hit play button after it throws the exception, it works fine. But, someone has to watch for it and hit the play button. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
FileLocation = "D:\TempSaveToMail\" & CoCode & Batch & ".pdf"

                On Error Resume Next
                Kill FileLocation
                On Error GoTo 0

                myReport.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = FileLocation
                myReport.ExportOptions.DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile
                myReport.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTPortableDocFormat
                myReport.ExportOptions.PDFExportAllPages = False
                myReport.ExportOptions.PDFFirstPageNumber = StartPage
                myReport.ExportOptions.PDFLastPageNumber = EndPage
                myReport.Export False

                '   Make printer friendly check the PDF image
                ImageReferenceNumber = InsertImage(CoCode, FileLocation)
                ReferenceNumber = GetReferenceNumber(CoCode, EmpNo, CheckNumber, Batch)
                InsertPDFImages CoCode, EmpNo, Batch, ReferenceNumber, ImageReferenceNumber
```

Comment: Dose it generate one report for EACH employees ?  Or is it a one BIG report

Comment: It generates one report for EACH employee. So, if you have 1000 employees, it would be 1000 PDF documents.

Answer (score 0):

You are not disposing your report objects resulting in memory leaks

After each employee dispose your report using

```
 for each employee
      myreport = new report

      //do all processing here

     myReport.dispose

  next employee
```

This should work

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am not sure if it is visual basic 6.0 code or something else but, I don't have access to myReport.dispose. At the end of the loop, we do set myReport = Nothing. Not sure if it matters but we declared myReport as a Global variable.

Comment: Oh i am sorry. I assumed you are using vb.net. That was my mistake. Just check if you have myReport.Close Option

Comment: I don't have the myReport.Close option either. The data type for my report is CRAXDRT.Report